# Getting "unresolved reference: android" error while implementing native Kotlin code in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am quite new to android studio and trying things around flutter. Tried to write some android specific code in MainActivity.kt and getting red squiggly lines under android package. Official android dev docs also publishing this code as the right method to import.

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.ContextWrapper
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.content.IntentFilter
    import android.os.BatteryManager
```

also getting the same squiggly red line under androidx.
Error is same : Coudln't Found Reference: adnroidx

```
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull
```

Googled for it but no clue found so far.
Also tried to create a new flutter project and made sure that support for kotlin and swift is checked but to no avail.

So only way left is to ask stack overflow community.

Here is the build.gradle inside android directory

```
     buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

and here is the build.gradle in android/app directory

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28

        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }

        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }

        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.firstapp"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle.properties file add:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: can you add your build.gradle (root directory of android and app directory android)

Comment: reinstalled the android studio with default locations but still no luck

Comment: added build.gradle files